# Nested HashMap with depth level of 3 and populating Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, hashmap

There is a field to hold average value of the calls.

But this average value calculation is based on few conditions on call type and call direction.

- Valid call directions are

  - incoming
  - outgoing
- Valid call types are

  - national
  - international
  - others

Trying to add the map with `Map<SummaryObject, Integer>`.

```
@Data
@EqualsOgnoreCase
class SummaryObject {
    String direction;
    String callType;
}
```

So this map will have:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Incoming, National | 50 |
| Incoming, International | 40 |
| Outgoing, National | 40 |

etc.

I have to populate this in the Excel sheet as depicted as:

```
Incoming                                        Outgoing
National International Others National International Others

50        40            0     40        0             0
```

etc.

Each row is identified with group name.

Is there an alternative data structure will be more appropriate for adding the details in the represented way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like you want `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` where the outer `Map` key is _call direction_ and the inner `Map` key is _call type_. How do you populate the `Map<SummaryObject, Integer>`? Are you using [POI](https://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: There are one more field also be added have values like ' call answered , call abandoned'. So , thinking to add Map structure according to that.